# Assumptions when proving that two saturated air masses mix to form supersaturated conditions using Clausius-Clapeyron

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science

Problem from an assignment:

> Prove that two saturated air masses of temperature $T$ and $T+{\Delta}T$ mix to form supersaturated conditions using the Clausius-Clapeyron relation:
>
> $\Large\frac{de_s}{e_s}=\frac{L_vdT}{R_vT^2}$

The correct method was given by prof as proving $\frac{d^2e_s}{dT^2}>0$

Could you also prove this by using a Taylor expansion about $T$? You cannot assume that ${\Delta}T$ is very small, but can you assume that if it can be proven for small ${\Delta}T$ it must be true for large ${\Delta}T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to assume that $\Delta T$ is small, your results are **not** valid for finite $\Delta T$. If you can prove that it's correct for *any* infinitely small $dT$ you could prove that it translates (by integration) to a finite $\Delta T$. However at this point it's easier to simply think about what happens really and (as your prof suggested)  just proving that the saturation pressure is a convex curve of temperature, that is the "average" of 2 saturation pressures is higher than the saturation pressure of the average temp.